# Question on a certain reduced isogeny of CM elliptic curves

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, complex-multiplication, isogenies

My question has to do with some hypotheses showing up in a Lemma of Joseph Silverman's Advanced Topics book.  Here is some of the set up:

Let $K$ be an imaginary quadratic field and $E/H$ an elliptic curve with complex multiplication by $O_K$ (the ring of integers of $K$) and defined over the Hilbert class field $H$.  Fix a prime $p$ such that $p$ splits as $pO_K = \mathfrak{p}\bar{\mathfrak{p}}$.  Let $\Lambda$ be a lattice for $E$.  Then the map
\begin{align*}\mathbb{C}/\Lambda \xrightarrow{z \mapsto z} \mathbb{C}/\bar{\frak{p}}\Lambda
\end{align*}
induces a map $E \to \bar{\mathfrak{p}}*E$, where $\bar{\mathfrak{p}}*E(\mathbb{C}) \cong \mathbb{C}/\bar{\frak{p}}\Lambda$.

**Lemma 4.5 of Chapter II in Silverman's book (top of page 128)**: Let $E$ be an elliptic curve with CM by $O_K$, and suppose that $E$ is defined over a number field $L$.  Then for all but finitely many degree 1 primes $\mathfrak{p}$ of $K$, the natural map $E \to \bar{\mathfrak{p}}*E$ has degree $p$ and its reduction $\tilde{E} \to \widetilde{\bar{\mathfrak{p}}*E}$ is purely inseparable (we reduce modulo some prime $\mathfrak{P}$ of $L$ lying above $\frak{p}$).

The "finitely many primes" are described at the top of page 126.  They satisfy at least one of the following three conditions: Let $E_1, E_2, \dots, E_n$ represent the isomorphism classes of elliptic curves with CM by $O_K$.

1. $p$ ramifies in $L$
2. some $E_i$ has bad reduction at some prime of $L$ lying over $p$
3. $p$ divides either the numerator or the denominator of one of the numbers $N_{L/\mathbb{Q}}(j(E_i) - j(E_k))$ for some $i \neq k$

The proof of Lemma 4.5 is contained in the proof of Proposition 4.2 (pages 125-127).

**My question:**  Do we need to exclude the primes satisfying items (1) and (3) for Lemma 4.5?  I can't quite see where item (1) is used in the proof of Proposition 4.2.  But, more importantly for what I'm trying to do, I can't see where (1) and (3) are used to show that the reduced map $\tilde{E} \to \widetilde{\bar{\mathfrak{p}}*E}$ is inseparable.  It seems like (3) is only needed so that when you reduce two different curves modulo $\mathfrak{P}$ you don't get the same $j$-invariant (the last paragraph in the proof).

The reduced isogenies are not really defined in Silverman's book (c.f. page 9 of the [errata](https://www.math.brown.edu/johsilve/ATAEC/ATAECErrata.pdf)), so I am also wondering if item (1) has to do with certain properties of the reduced isogenies used in the proof of Proposition 4.2.

Thank you in advance for any help!